# Error handling SnowflakeDbCommand with incorrect Database and/or Schema

Tags: c#, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm facing an issue in my C# dotnet core rest API where I have to enable the user to get data from any Snowflake database and schema at their choosing. This is by design and for a bunch of reasons that aren't relevant to the question.

I want to gracefully handle the case where the user hits my API with a database that doesn't exist, and furthermore a schema that doesn't exist within that database. With bad data in the connection string this works:

```
var conn = var conn = new SnowflakeDbConnection {ConnectionString = database.connectionString};
await conn.OpenAsync();
sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout;
```

Then this is where things break:

```
await using var reader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken);
```

If I wrap the line above in a `try {} catch {}` I get this after waiting quite some time:

```
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.RestRequester.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, TimeSpan timeoutPerRestRequest, CancellationToken externalCancellationToken)
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.RestRequester.PostAsync[T](IRestRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Snowflake.Data.Core.SFStatement.ExecuteAsync(Int32 timeout, String sql, Dictionary`2 bindings, Boolean describeOnly, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Then right after the app crashes with a pretty meaningless stack trace, a bunch of tasks cancelled in an aggregated exception.

Any advice on how to handle this? Ideally we get the operation cancellation exception earlier by some set timeout, but at the very least I need to handle this without the app crashing.

Edit: I should add that when this occurs the `cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` remains `False`. Perhaps this is a bug in `SnowflakeDbCommand`? Perhaps I need to cancel manually?

Comment: This will require some testing, but in the meantime I have something that you may want to investigate. Are you passing the DB and schema in the connection? If so, you may want to try connecting without specifying either a database or a schema. Then before running anything else, do two ExecuteNonQuery using the statements "use database WHATEVER_DB_NAME" and then another ExecuteNonQuery "use schema WHATEVER_SCHEMA". This will set the context for the session, but it will also error out if one of the two does not exist. It will also let you know which one is incorrect.

Comment: That's a good idea. Right now I just put the db and schema in the connection string, and then execute the query straight away.

Comment: After a quick first test of that idea, it does seem to work. Unfortunately, it means I'll have to refactor a chunk of my common database connectivity code. More importantly, it also means 2 prerequisite queries for each single query that I run, which is not idea from a performance perspective. There really must (or should) be a proper way the Snowflake C# libraries handle this.

Comment: Good to know it works if nothing else as a workaround. If you're in control of the SQL, you can avoid the two context-setting statements by always sending fully-qualified object names in your queries. If your users of the API will have control of the SQL, it will require setting the context either in the connection or in the session with "use" statements.

Comment: The users will control what db and schema, but I'm in control of what I do with those selections. So yes, I could use stitch together some fully qualified SQL. Likely that's what I'll do here, although I still stand by the "Snowflake libs should handle this" better. Perhaps don't allow connections to open against dbs and schemas that don't exist!

Comment: The downside of stitching together the fully qualified SQL is I won't be able to tell the user which of the 3 they went wrong in - db name, schema name, or table name...

Comment: Correction, the error thrown reports that information.

Comment: Hey @GregPavlik, I'm getting SQL compilation errors for unexpected '?' in my parameterized sql to fully qualify these queries. I'm just doing `select * from ?.?.?` and plugging in the 3 parameters. It does work if I build the string myself, however.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it's too late, but would helpful for people who have suffered. I faced the same issue and I tried using IDbConnection is sorted out from this pretty meaningless exception.

```
using (IDbConnection connection = new SnowflakeDbConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = alstrConnectionString;
                connection.Open();
                obj = await connection.QueryAsync<T>(aStrSPName, adynamicParameters);
                connection.Close();
            }
```

Now, you will get an exception with proper message if passed wrong schema/DB/Warehouse and credentials.